# C# Linq query not working

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I've a `Dictionary<MyEntity1, IList<MyEntity2>>` and I have an object of MyEntity2 which I know it is in one (and only one) of the lists of the dictionary (I've even seen it while debugging). How ever the following query is returning null:

```
IDictionary<MyEntity1, IList<MyEntity2>> myDictionary = new Dictionoary<MyEntity1, IList<MyEntity2>>();
MyEntity1 myEntity1 = (from p in myDictionary
                       where p.Value.Contains(myEntity2)
                       select p.Key) as MyEntity1;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please edit your post so the full definition of Dictionary<MyEntity1, IList<MyEntity2>> is visible

Comment: Ok, I'll edit it, but the answer posted a few seconds ago worked (I didn't get to see who posted it).

Comment: @Richard Morgan: no, I'm not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var myEntity1 = (from p in myDictionary
                where p.Value.Contains(myEntity2)
                select p.Key).First();
```

LINQ queries always return collections, even if with only one object instance

Comment: Will this return null if no object found?

Comment: @Diego: no, it will not return null... it will throw an exception if not found.  use.FirstOrDefault() if you want a null instead.

Answer (score 1):

You should use something like

```
   MyEntity1 myEntity1 = (from p in myDictionary
                   where p.Value.Contains(myEntity2)
                   select p.Key).FirstOrDefault();
```

The query will return an `IEnumerable<MyEntity1>` and casting that to `MyEntity1` will always return null. The cast is invalid and  `as` will return null.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the Select query returns an IEnumerable - which you can't cast to MyEntity1.

Try adding `FirstOrDefault()` - then you won't need the cast.

```
IDictionary<MyEntity1, IList<MyEntity2>> myDictionary = new Dictionary<MyEntity1, IList<MyEntity2>>();
var myEntity1 = (from p in myDictionary
                   where p.Value.Contains(myEntity2)
                   select p.Key).FirstOrDefault();
```